# Interacting with dictionaries and lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
dict={'OR.PA':0.75,'TEF.MC':0.111,'FB':0.44,'YHOO':0.77,'AMZN':0.222 }
```

on the other side I have the following list :

```
list=['AMZN','OR.PA','TEF.MC','FB','YHOO']
```

How can I return a list with the values that correspond to each of the keys in the dictionary in the order that appears in the tickers' list ?

This would be the desired output:

```
list=[ 0.222,0.75,0.111,0.44,0.77]
```

I know how to iterate with the  keys or values based on a same dictionary, but it is the first time I am dealing with a dictionary on one side and a list in the other. Thank you for reading my post

Comment: `[dct[k] for k in lst]`

Comment: And be careful about using built-ins as custom object names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
my_dict = {'OR.PA':0.75,'TEF.MC':0.111,'FB':0.44,'YHOO':0.77,'AMZN':0.222 }
other_list = ['AMZN','OR.PA','TEF.MC','FB','YHOO']
res_list = [my_dict[x] for x in other_list]
```

Do not use names such as `list` and `dict`. You rename functions when you do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
d={'OR.PA':0.75,'TEF.MC':0.111,'FB':0.44,'YHOO':0.77,'AMZN':0.222 }
l=['AMZN','OR.PA','TEF.MC','FB','YHOO']
out=[d[x] for x in l]
print(out) # = [0.222, 0.75, 0.111, 0.44, 0.77]
```

Explanation:

- `out=[...]` will build a new list
- `d[x]` will access the dictionary value
- `for x in l` will iterate your list in order

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

dict={'OR.PA':0.75,'TEF.MC':0.111,'FB':0.44,'YHOO':0.77,'AMZN':0.222 }
list=['AMZN','OR.PA','TEF.MC','FB','YHOO']

values = itemgetter(*list)(dict)

print(values)
(0.222, 0.75, 0.111, 0.44, 0.77)

# Convert tuple to list
values = [t for t in values]

print(values)
[0.222, 0.75, 0.111, 0.44, 0.77]
```